# How to get a list using java method in velocity template

Tags: java, templates, collections, velocity

I am trying to get a List instance in velocity template using:

```
#set($list = ${Foo.BarList}.getList())
```

but I am getting an error.

Foo.Barlist has a method of getList that returns a List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the curly brackets which is not needed in velocity

```
#set($list = $Foo.BarList.getList())
```

Or move the right one after method call:

```
#set($list = ${Foo.BarList.getList()})
```